# Can't ping or connect to wireless projector

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, projector, peer-to-peer

I have an Epson Powerlite 1264 wireless projector set up on my corporate network. When I first installed it I was able to connect to it while on my wireless LAN no problem. After about a week I was no longer able to connect to it that way. I can still connect to it if I am direct connected to my LAN. I can ping while direct connected as well. Once on wireless I can no longer connect or ping the device. I know this is a peer to peer issue and was wondering if there was a way where I could get this working on my wireless network without allowing all peer to peer access on the network?

Answer (score 1):

That it worked for a week and then stopped working is a big factor. That suggests the device got moved into a different security group that's accessible over the wired network IP range (commonly known as the 'safe' or 'green' zone) but not addresses given to wireless users (the 'not company owned' or 'blue' zone), potentially following an SNMP trap scanner of some sort (SpiceWorks, for instance) detected it.  I'd recommend either looking into the company's firewall configuration (if you've got access to it) or talking to who does as that's the most likely factor in network traffic access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of any configuration changes on you WiFi network because it sounds like you have "wireless isolation" enabled on your WiFi network. 
Most probably because of this feature you're not able to connect to your WiFi projector while being on WiFi.

Comment: I am not aware of any changes that were made to the WiFi network.